# PHP uft8_encode / utf8_decode with double quotation problem

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, quotation-marks

I have a problem with utf8_encode / utf8_decode PHP function.This function must be complementary.

I know that:

- utf8_decode convert UTF8 string to ISO-8859-1
- utf8_encode convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF8

But if I try to convert and return back the character **LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK** the behaviour is different.
I expect that this two echo print the same character, but this not occurs.

```
<?php
$doubleQuote = hex2bin("e2809c");
var_dump($doubleQuote);
$doubleQuoteNew = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($doubleQuote));
var_dump($doubleQuoteNew);
```

this is the output

```
/tmp/test.php:3:
string(3) "“"
/tmp/test.php:5:
string(1) "?"
```

Instead using simple character the two echo return the same.
I try with php version 5 and 7.

Where is my wrong ??

Comment: "This function must be complementary" - Kind of. UTF-8 is a Unicode compatible encoding so it can store all characters (143,859 at the time of writing). ISO-8859-1 is a legacy single byte encoding, thus limited to 256 characters (less than that in practice).

Comment: Thank, with your explanation I understand my error.

Answer (score 3):

The Latin-1 encoding [does not contain any "fancy quote" character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout). There's no equivalent character that the Unicode `“` character could be converted to in Latin-1, so it gets replaced with a `?`. That in turn can perfectly be converted back to UTF-8.